# [A-Z][0-9] how to alter to get OR on the string matching

Tags: regex

REgex wise, how do i change this to allow not any A-Z. But 3 types (like an OR)

PORT or CW or TW

Then the 0-9 part

i.e. a valid one has to start with 1 of the 3 strings above followed by some numbers?

Comment: `(PORT|CW|TW)\d`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty much the same as previous answers but I include the minimum length of the number.

```
(PORT|CW|TW)[0-9]{8,}
```

**Definition:** {min length, max length}

**Demo:** https://regex101.com/r/SjuTyZ/1

Answer (score 0):

This is the one you are looking for:

```
(PORT|CW|TW)\d+
```

https://regex101.com/r/EQnB2g/1

**1st Capturing Group (PORT|CW|TW)**

- **1st Alternative PORT**

  - PORT matches the characters PORT literally (case sensitive)
- **2nd Alternative CW**

  - CW matches the characters CW literally (case sensitive)
- **3rd Alternative TW**

  - TW matches the characters TW literally (case sensitive)

Comment: Or if you just wanna catch the number only, then use Positive Lookbehind as `(?<=PORT|CW|TW)\d+`

Answer (score 0):

If you have definitely some numbers after the text, then the regex is:

```
(?:PORT|CW|TW)\d+
```

The **?:** will help you to non-capture the matched group.